# CSS Browser Support Chart

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

Is there any resource that provides a chart of CSS properties and their support through most browser/OS combinations? For example, if I want to know what browser supports `overflow` or `min-height` and any quirks to be aware of in the implementation of these properties and their values, what is the best place to get all this?

I have found a couple places but I haven't been impressed.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

Quriks mode is also a really good resource for this sort of information.

Answer (score 6):

caniuse.com is very helpful in this manner as well. And you can also check other implementations like HTML5 or SVG support there.
http://caniuse.com/

Answer (score 5):

The wikipedia article is fairly impressive and a good place to start:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CSS_support

Comment: That's the one I am currently using and I don't really like it. I was hoping there was something better out there but I guess it'll have to do.

Comment: I know what you mean.  It's pretty... variable, but I find if nothing else it gets me to a better follow-up google search.

Answer (score 4):

Most of the CSS reference sites I used to use are out of date, but SitePoint recently (I'd say the past year) released a [CSS Reference](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css) that is kept up to date and is easy to navigate.

Comment: For example, right now I want to know how overflow-x is supported across browsers. That SitePoint site is exactly what I want but they don't have overflow-x on there which makes me question how through it is immediately.