# Book or website which lists browser compatibility for all CSS elements?

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

I am looking for a resource (book or website) which lists all the CSS elemenets' compatibility with the major browsers. It has to include information for IE8 & FireFox3 (Chrome not too important). The ones I have found do **not** mention IE8 so I need one that's up to date to include IE6, IE7 and **IE8**.

For example, if I want to use 'border-spacing', I want to know which browser does not support it, if any.

Comment: possible duplicate of [CSS Browser Support Chart](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203208/css-browser-support-chart)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quirksmode, hands down:

http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html

In particular, for your question on `border_spacing`: http://www.quirksmode.org/css/tables.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/203208/css-browser-support-chart :p